# Botón para imprimir y guardar com imagen (contenido de una pagina Web) conservando estilos

Tags: php, jquery, html5, imprimir

Quisiera darle la función a un boton para imprimir el contenido html  y y a otro para descargar el contenido html como una imagen. no se si  esto sea posible¿?

Comment: [edit] la pregunta para que te se entienda mejor la pregunta

Comment: intentaste algo hasta el momento? compartenos el código de lo que has hecho para poder ayudarte!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es librerías de terceros, puesto a que directamente el navegador no renderiza HTML a un formato imagen. Con esto:

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Conviertes la sección web que quieras a canvas, y después basta con hacer

```
window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Para que tengas un link directo a la imagen generada, cuidado con los detalles puesto a que el render no es 100% exacto. Para la impresión se podría directamente del botón con:

```
window.print();
```

Y con CSS puedes seleccionar el área a mostrar